# Q: Get ancestors with a node in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Here is the reference link that I used to create procedures: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161?newreg=88de047579d242c98b8cfe0e17f0330f

Procedures are working well with the example. But not working in my own database. Seems I do something wrong while creating procedures.
Here is the procedure for my db:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `demo`.`GetParentIDByID` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `demo`.`GetParentIDByID` (GivenID INT) RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE rv INT;

    SELECT IFNULL(user_by,-1) INTO rv FROM
    (SELECT user_by FROM users WHERE id = GivenID) A;
    RETURN rv;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sql query for the following procedure is working fine. It is basically getting parent_id of the node:

```
SELECT id,GetParentIDByID(id) FROM users;
```

Issue occurs when I am try to get Ancestors. Here is the Procedure that I am using:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `demo`.`GetAncestry` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `demo`.`GetAncestry` (GivenID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE rv VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE cm CHAR(1);
    DECLARE ch INT;

    SET rv = '';
    SET cm = '';
    SET ch = GivenID;
    WHILE ch > 0 DO
        SELECT IFNULL(user_by,-1) INTO ch FROM
        (SELECT user_by FROM users WHERE id = ch) A;
        IF ch > 0 THEN
            SET rv = CONCAT(rv,cm,ch);
            SET cm = ',';
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN rv;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT id,GetAncestry(id) FROM users;
```

Phpmyadmin getting stuck, if I am using this query. It never returns me anything nor an error or success[image: Stucked]